# How to check internet connectivity using pinging multiple IP's

Tags: bash, unix

I need a bash script for checking internet connectivity.
I used the below one first.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while true; do
if ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 &> /dev/null
then
  echo "internet working"
else
  echo "no internet"
fi
sleep 5
done
```

It works fine but fails sometimes. So I was looking for something that would do ping test on multiple IP's, this way only one of the IP has to ping successfully to assume connectivity.
I am extremely new to bash, so apologies for any mistakes.

How do I correct the below script so it works as intended?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while true; do 
count= '0'
if ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 &> /dev/null
then
count= '1'
fi

if ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/null
then
count= count + '1'
fi

if ping -c 1 www.google.com &> /dev/null
then
count= count + '1'
fi

if [ count -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "no internet"
else
  echo "internet working"
fi

sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the commands in the if statement:

```
if ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 || ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 || ping -c 1 www.google.com
then
  echo "One of the above worked"
else
  echo "None of the above worked" >&2
fi
```

And if needed then you can ofcause still redirect the output of the `ping` command.

```
if ping ... > /dev/null # redirect stdout
if ping ... 2> /dev/null # redirect stderr
if ping ... &> /dev/null # redirect both (but not POSIX) `>/dev/null 2>&1` is though.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a function for this task, so that I can pass the hosts to be pinged as arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check internet connectivity
# Returns true if ping succeeds for any argument. Returns false otherwise
ckintconn () {
    for host
    do
        ping -c1 "$host" && return
    done
    return 1
} &>/dev/null

if ckintconn 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 www.google.com
then
    echo "internet working"
else
    echo "no internet"
fi
```